# Parametric equation involving exponents and e

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

How do you go about solving this problem?

> For each plane curve given below, find a rectangular equation. State the appropritate interval for $x$ and $y$.
>
> $x(t) = e^{5t}$, $y(t) = e^t$, $t \in (-\infty, \infty)$.
>
> Which is the correct rectangular equation?
>
> (a) $x = \frac 1{y^5}$
>
> (b) $y = x^5$
>
> (c) $y = \frac 1{x^5}$
>
> (d) $x = y^5$.

Comment: $ x(t) = (e^t)^5 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are given alternatives, you can simply plug in and check:

(A) $x = 1/y^5$ gives $e^{5t} = 1/(e^t)^5$, which is not true. So (A) is wrong.

Etc.